# Como fazer uma linha vertical

Tags: html, css

Olá queria saber como faz uma linha em vertical com este código:

```
<hr>
```

Ela por padrão é horizontal, queria muito ela vertical, alguém sabe como faz? Queria justo este código pois tenho ele em vertical em meu site também.

Comment: Poderia editar seu post e colocar o código em questão?

Comment: Tinha colocado mais bugo, concertei

Comment: Sim, desse estilo dela

Comment: Você teria que fazer com CSS e HTML, porque não tem linha vertical em HTML puro.

Comment: Pior que não sei fazer isto pois sou iniciante :(

Comment: Dei um exemplo na minha resposta, verifica se é isso que você quer.

Comment: Tem muitas maneiras de se fazer uma linha vertical em HTML, seria legal você por seu código original aqui e explicar em qual parte é a linha vertical, para podermos propor uma alternativa que sirva melhor pro seu caso. Da forma como está a pergunta, fica um pouco ampla, mas se tiver um pouco mais de contexto, acho que fica legal.

Answer (score 7):

Você pode adicionar linha vertical com HTML e CSS da seguinte forma:

```css
.linha-vertical {
  height: 500px;/*Altura da linha*/
  border-left: 2px solid;/* Adiciona borda esquerda na div como ser fosse uma linha.*/
}
```

```html
<div class="linha-vertical"></div>
```

Você pode colocar linha no centro usando dois elementos `<div>`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```css
.box {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 height: 300px;/*Altura da linha*/
}

.linha-vertical {
 border-left: 2px solid;/* Adiciona borda esquerda na div como ser fosse uma linha.*/
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<div class="box linha-vertical">

</div>
```

Comment: Qual é o nome no CSS para colocar no meio? Tipo assim: .linha-vertical {
  height: 500px;/*Altura da linha*/
  border-center: 2px solid;/
}

Comment: Para colocar a linha vertical com border no css não daria para colocar no centro do elemente html, mas você pode fazer isso alterando o tamanho do elemento.

Comment: Verifica no outro exemplo que eu fiz, se não é isso que você está querendo fazer.

Comment: No 2 código praticamente ela ficou no meio, mas aonde aumenta o tamanho é aonde? No  border-left: 2px solid;? , height: 200px;/*Altura da linha*/ ? ou width: 40%;?

Comment: No height: 200px;/*Altura da linha*/

Comment: Eu aumentei mais ela não saiu do lugar, queria que ela fosse para o meio :(

Comment: Para deixa-lá no meio, faça: width: 50%, da forma como eu alterei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Este "código" na verdade é uma marcação HTML para criar uma linha na horizontal.

No PHP não existem funções que renderizam HTML na pagina. Acredito que o que você possa fazer é;

Criar uma div, colocar o border (esquerda ou direita) com a cor e espessura  que quiser e ira irá gerar uma linha.

Comment: Mas ela ficaria vertical? .-.

Comment: sim, porque a div seria uma "caixa" só com a borda esquerda/direita colorida, o resto não teria.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly você explicou bem o conceito de marcação html, mas aconselho a colocar um exemplo prático do que deve ser feito para resolver o problema. No caso, um exemplo css. Assim sua resposta fica completa.